# What does this (simple?) expression in Python mean? func(self)(*args)

Tags: python, getattr

I saw some Python code like: `getattr(self, that)(*args)`. what does it mean? I see that the builtin `getattr` function gets called, passing the current object and `that`; but what is the `(*args)` doing after that? Does it call something with `*args` as parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right on track.  `that` is going to be the name of a method on the object.  `getattr()` is returning that method (function) and then calling it.  Because functions are first class members they can be passed around, returned, etc.

Answer (score 3):

It calls the value returned by `getattr(self, that)` with the arguments specified in the array `args`.

For example, assuming `that = 'thatFunction'` and `args = [1,2,3]`, it's the same as

```
self.thatFunction(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

It calls the method of self whose name is held in `that` and passing `*args` as the arguments to the function. `args` is a tuple and `*args` is special syntax that allows you to call a function and expand a tuple into a list of arguments.

Suppose that `that` contained the string `'f'`, and `args` was `(1,2,3)`, then `getattr(self, that)(*args)` would be equivalent to:

```
self.f(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

`getattr()` fetches the attribute of `self` named by the string variable `that`.  The return value, i.e. the attribute named by `that`, is then called with the arguments given by the iterable `args`.

Assuming `that` has the value `"foo"`, the following four lines are equivalent:

```
self.foo(*args)

f = self.foo; f(*args)

f = getattr(self, that); f(*args)

getattr(self, that)(*args)
```

Using `*args` as parameter is the same as using all of the items in `args` as spearate parameters.